# Alter [marshallislands] to [marshall-islands]

Tags: support, tags

This is related to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/50772/28994) about the Marshall Islands; the new tag [marshallislands](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marshallislands) has been created which does not have a space in, making it inconsistent with other tags such as [republic-of-ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-ireland) or [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). I've tried to delete the tag from the question and apply the correct spelling, but I get an error that it is too similar to the existing incorrect tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.

I don't know what else to write to satisfy the 30 character limit.